# How to print out two way circular linked list?

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

so I wrote a code for two-way circular linked list (unordered), in C, and I've run into a problem. I have this code for printing out the elements (starting from head):

```
void ShowListFromHead(List& l){
    if(l.head==l.tail){
        printf("%d", l.head->value);
        return;
    }
    Element* p;
    p=l.head;
    while(p->next!= l.head){
        printf("%d,", p->value);
        p=p->next;}
}
```

It works fine except for the tail, since the while loop works until it reaches tail (until p->next is the head). So, here's my question: is there a way to show the whole list without excluding any element? It seems that however I formulate the loop, there is always one element left out. Using do/while loop isn't working either. I tried just adding one printf after the loop for the last element, but it messes up the functionality of other functions in the code. I'm trying to fix this for a couple of days and still have no idea how to, so any help is highly appreciated!

EDIT I'm adding the deleteHead function, it appears that maybe the problem isn't entirely in show function.

```
bool deleteHead(List& l, int &oldHead){
        if(l.head!=NULL){
            oldHead= l.head->value;
            Element *p=l.head;
            if(l.head->next!=NULL){
                l.head=l.head->next;
                l.head->prev=l.tail;
                l.tail->next=l.head;
                delete p;
                return true;
            }}
        else if(l.head==NULL){
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does printing the tail value mess up the other functions? A print statement shouldn't change the contents of your list.

Comment: This code is not c code, it's c++. There is no pass by reference in c.

Comment: @iharob sorry, thanks for the edit :)

Comment: @mstbaum when I try to delete head or tail when it's the only element on the list, it keeps displaying that element instead of the empty list, as it should have. I thought maybe the functions were written wrong but I checked and when I threw out the additional printf it worked.

Comment: @Pauline then it sounds like your issue is in your delete function.  The printf is not messing up your delete's functionality, but printing the element that you didn't actually delete.

Comment: @mstbaum hm yeah I thought so, but deleting the problematic part in show function made it work alright, even though I haven't changed anything in delete function! I'm gonna add it too, could you take a look? Maybe you'll be able to see some mistakes.

Comment: @Pauline Your problem is that you never actually delete the last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modification to the original code:

```
void ShowListFromHead(List& l){
    if(l.head == 0)
        return;
    Element* p = l.head;
    do{
        printf("%d,", p->value);
        p=p->next;
    }while (p != l.head);
}
```

or

```
void ShowListFromHead(List& l){
    if(l.head == 0)
        return;
    Element* p = l.head;
    do{
        std::cout << p->value << ", " ;
        p=p->next;
    }while (p != l.head);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you were having issues using a print statement after your loop is because of your delete code:

```
bool deleteHead(List& l, int &oldHead){
    if(l.head!=NULL){
        oldHead= l.head->value;
        Element *p=l.head;
        if(l.head->next!=NULL){
            l.head=l.head->next;
            l.head->prev=l.tail;
            l.tail->next=l.head;
        } // this is where you should close your if statement
            delete p;
            return true;
        //} you don't account for the case where there is one element left
    }
    else if(l.head==NULL){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you could add the print statement to print the tail after your loop. Or you could implement @rcgldr 's solution.  I like this one:

```
void ShowListFromHead(List& l){
    if(l.head == 0)
        return;
    Element* p = l.head;
    do{
        printf("%d,", p->value);
        p=p->next;
    }while (p != l.head);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, I changed it this way and I think I got it, the thing is, I guess it deletes it but it prints out a couple of random values instead of showing an empty line. Starts with the last deleted value and then numbers like 1398975. Do you know why is it happening? I'm sorry for that many questions, but I really want to finish it right :)

Comment: though wait, why do I have to close the if statement there? It's a circular list, so tail will never technically be null...

Comment: The reason it prints random values is because when your list is empty, you still try to print the head, which is pointing to random data.  The reason you have to close the if statement where I said is so you still delete the last element in the list.  When you are down to the last element, head->next will be null, and tail will point to the same thing as head, so when you delete it, tail will be null.  Make sense?